# Control de prefijos de Namespace en Web Services

Tags: web, wcf, servicio

Saludos, estoy intentando el desarrollo de un Web Service para un sistema de transacciones bancarias basado en el estándar ISO 20022 con documentos Payment, Clearing an Settlement (PACS) tipos 008 y 005 (PACS.008.04 y PACS.005.06).

El Web Service es del tipo WCF con C# en Visual Studio 2015, tome los XSD de los PACS.008 y PACS.005 y genere clases con etiquetas del XML usando el comando XSD del Developer Prompt.

La dificultad que tengo es la siguiente, en la imagen que muestro a continuación se ve el Request obtenido desde el WS central del banco:

[image: Vista del Request obtenido del WS del banco]
Notese como el miembro FIToFICstmrCdtTrf tiene el prefijo urn del namespace  urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04,lo cual es correcto y asi debo generar mi Web Service.

Ahora bien, al generar mi Web Service con el siguiente codigo de interface y contratos:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "NamespaceDelServicio"), XmlSerializerFormat, DispatchByBodyBehavior]
public interface IST
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "", Name = "hacerDeposito")]
    respuesta depositarDineroVC(transaccion input);

    [OperationContract(Action = "", Name = "hacerRetiro")]
    string retirarDineroVC(response x);
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "hacerDeposito", WrapperNamespace = "NamespaceDelServicio")]
public class transaccion
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "documentoDeposito", Namespace = "", Order = 1)]
    public pacs008 documentoDeposito;
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "ip", Namespace = "", Order = 2)]
    public string ip;
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "usuario", Namespace = "", Order = 3)]
    public string usr;
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "depositarDineroVCResponse", WrapperNamespace = "NamespaceDelServicio")]
public class respuesta
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public respuestaTransaccion documentoRespuestaSolicitudDeposito;
}


[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "FIToFICstmrCdtTrf", WrapperNamespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04")]
public class pacs008
{
    [MessageBodyMember()]
    public PACS008.FIToFICustomerCreditTransferV04 FIToFICstmrCdtTrf;
}

public class respuestaTransaccion
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.002.001.05")]
    public PACS005.FIToFIPaymentStatusReportV05 FIToFIPmtStsRpt;
}
```

El request obtenido es el siguiente:

[image: Request de mi web service]

Observese como no esta el prefijo urn que es necesario, ya que si se usa el Web Service sin dicho prefijo, no se detecta el documento FIToFICstmrCdtTrf porque no esta en el namespace y se obtiene un null a la hora de procesar el Request.

Si dentro de la clase transacción modifico la linea:

```
[MessageBodyMember(Name = "documentoDeposito", Namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04", Order = 1)]
public pacs008 documentoDeposito;
```

Entonces el prefijo aparece en el FIToFICstmrCdtTrf pero tambien en el Wrapper documentoDeposito lo cual no es conveniente, he intentado varias combinaciones de la declaracion de Namespace o crear subclases decoradas con MessageContract para intentar la estructura necesaria pero no me ha sido posible.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Estimado,
Como solucionaste el problema, tengo el mismo problema Saludos,

Comment: Saludos Juan, ya no recuerdo despues de tanto tiempo, trato de mirar el codigo para ver si aun puedo recordar, disculpas!